# How to enable Horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

[Here](http://www.eklavya.in/pitara) on this page I need to display the SPACIAL and RECOMMENDED section in in single line with horizontal-scroll.

My current css is

```
.box-product {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

I have tried like this

```
.box-product {
width: 100%;
height: 320px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

But it does not enable horizontal scroll, It still shows the vertical scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set width to `.box-product` equal to `product width * product count`. Nothing else.

Now, you have there `width: 100%;` (737px) and the default CSS behavior in this case is to break the content to another line. When you have there `overflow: hidden`, the second line is hidden.

Comment: When I entered width I got horizontal scroll but It's on home-container 
 And css for home-container  is

 #home-container {
overflow: auto;
background: #FFF;
border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
}

Answer (score 1):

Provide your `box-product class` width in `pixel` not in percentage. And than apply `overflow:auto`.

It will work.

Ex:
    .box-product {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    }

And if you want only horizontal than add `overflow-x:auto`;

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this `.box-product { width: max-content; }` (modulo vendor prefixes).

Alternatively `display: flex`, since its children do not wrap by default.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width: 100%` and make sure your content doesn't float.